# Converting chrono::duration type to std::tm type

Tags: c++, c++11, time, c++-chrono

I am writing a program that takes input a date from the user, uses it to initialize a `tm struct`, then using `chrono::time_points` performs some `chrono::duration` operation, such as getting the age.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  //representing a date
  tm *birthday  = new tm{00, 30, 00, 07, 11, 97};
  //convert to time t 
  time_t bt = mktime(birthday);
  //convert time_t to time_point
  chrono::system_clock::time_point t = chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(bt);
  chrono::system_clock::time_point now = chrono::system_clock::now();
  /*.. Testing 
  time_t nn = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
  time_t tnn = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(t);
  */

  chrono::system_clock::duration lft = now - t;
  //convert to timepoint
  chrono::system_clock::time_point tlft{lft};
  time_t lifetime = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(tlft);
  cout << put_time(localtime(&lifetime), "%F %T") << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

And my output is something like this:
     `$> 1990-02-10 09:42:46`

So, according to my understanding, it performs a plain mathematical subtraction on the ticks and using localtime, converts it to a date since `EPOCH` that is why it is giving me 1990. I want to know, is there any way, to convert the duration straight into `struct tm`, so that I should get something like 20 years?

Comment: Side note, its probably better to declare `tm birthday;` by value and pass its address to `mktime(&birthday);` to prevent potential memory leaks and because its much faster than allocating using `new`.

Comment: Also Howard Hinnant's `date` library is perfect for this and is being proposed for standardization: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Comment: why do you need the`tm` conversion ? if you don't need a chronologically precise result (eg. see @Galik comment) you may just `chrono::duration_cast<chrono::hours>(now - t).count()/(24*365)`

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes I use tm conversion because I want the flexibility to print the date in any format. In that case I chose "%F %T". I wanted something that will give me a full lifetime, let me call it timestamp, of an object. Full date and Full time. Your solution will allow me to extract year, how about the rest...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you extract a duration in the unit of your choice:

```
std::chrono::duration<double> lft = now - t;
using year = std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<31557600>>;
auto nby = std::chrono::duration_cast<year>(lft);
std::cout << nby.count() << "\n";
```

With this in mind, I'll suggest an implementation of the taste of:

```
struct Age
{
    using year   = std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<31'557'600>>;
    using month  = std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio< 2'592'000>>;
    using day    = std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<    86'400>>;
    using hour   = std::chrono::hours;
    using minute = std::chrono::minutes;
    using second = std::chrono::seconds;

    Age(std::chrono::system_clock::time_point birth)
        : _age(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - birth)
    {}

    template<class Duration>
    auto extract()
    {
        const auto result = std::chrono::duration_cast<Duration>(_age);
        _age -= result;
        return result;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Age age)
    {
         const auto years   = age.extract<year>();
         const auto monthes = age.extract<month>();
         const auto days    = age.extract<day>();
         const auto hours   = age.extract<hour>();
         const auto minutes = age.extract<minute>();
         const auto seconds = age.extract<second>();

         return os  << years.count()
                    << ":" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << monthes.count()
                    << ":" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << days.count()
                    << " " << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << hours.count()
                    << ":" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << minutes.count()
                    << ":" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << seconds.count()
                    ;
    }

private:
    std::chrono::duration<double> _age;
};
```

Prints [`20:01:10 12:43:40` with your example date (live demo)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1a52bc9749a1b8a).

Comment: How can I get the full date using this solution? Will I have to compute the individual values, i.e month, day, hour, secs e.t.c?

Comment: The output as something like this. `20-02-10 09:42:46` which is the qualified duration or lifetime of the object under consideration..

Comment: Forget the format. It represents the full age, not a date, of the object... Something that can be made to be interpreted as 20 yrs, 2 months, 10 days etcetera..

Comment: @xorhaxor My coffee was a bit hot, I had some time to write an implementation that should suits you. See updated post ;)

Comment: Challenge:  Currently the duration is 1 day off (Dec 7 + 1 month + 10 days == Jan 17).  Why?  How to fix it? :-)

Comment: @HowardHinnant by having more serious definitions of years and monthes ^^ But if you want a robust tool, you'd have to use a time&date library. On those scales of time difference, odd things can happen.

Comment: And even the question would need to be modified to be more precise.  What timezone was the birthday in?  If computer's local, are we assured that when we run the program we're in the same local timezone?  Otherwise it is very easy to fall into [false precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_precision) territory.

Comment: @HowardHinnant I'm sure you had that in mind when you first gave me that "challenge" :D imaright?

Comment: @HowardHinnant I saw this library and it's pretty cool, i could use it easily.. though the syntax or the expressivity of the library is a bit obscure.. https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Comment: If you have any questions about it, feel free to post a question on Stackoverflow, [gitter](https://gitter.im/HowardHinnant/date?utm_source=badge&utm_medium=badge&utm_campaign=pr-badge&utm_content=badge), or [submit an issue](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/issues).

Comment: @HowardHinnant Actually I can post one quick question here... I am confused by the use of `floor<Class precision>()` method to do conversion.. I am used to casting, is any special design decision you considered to use floor of cast?

Comment: `duration_cast` came with `chrono` in C++11.  That's also my fault, but I thought it best in 2008.  Anyway `duration_cast` truncates towards zero.  For C++20, three more "rounding modes" were added:  `floor` : truncate towards negative infinity; `round` : truncate towards nearest integer (to even on tie); `ceil` : truncate towards positive infinity.  Those new rounding modes are provided in date.h so that they can be used prior to C++20.  The "named casts" are useful since rounding is involved and there's more than one choice.

Comment: Actually these new chrono rounding modes are in C++17, not 20.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/floor

Comment: Is the library to be included in c++ 20? And also, is the date retrieval thread safe? @HowardHinnant

Comment: The library is working its way through the standardization process.  In my estimation it currently has a 60/40 chance (in favor) of getting into C++20.  The library was built to be as thread safe as an int.  Date retrieval is thread safe.  Time zone database initialization is thread safe.  Normal usage is thread safe.  Anything not marked with a "thread safety" paragraph in the documentation is thread safe.  A "thread safety" paragraph is there to discuss all thread safety issues that might arise with the function being documented.